# Me raft adventure mode map creator difficulties

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a map for adventure mode and adding a lever to be only placed on a moss stone I've searched on this site and every thing I try failed 
I thought this might work
/give @s lever 1 0 {canPlaceOn:[minecraft:moss_stone]}
Please send me the right code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374598/how-can-i-use-canplaceon-and-candestroy-in-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer from one of my own questions may be able to help:

/give @p minecraft:lever{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:mossy_cobblestone"]} 1

this should work if the map you are making is in 1.13

Comment: Wrong edition of the game.