# How can I use CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Java Edition has the `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` NBT tags, which are used to restrict the blocks an item can be placed on and destroy respectively (in adventure mode). For example, the following commands give the player a stone block that can only be placed on grass and dirt, and a netherite axe that can only destroy pumpkins:

```
give @s stone{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass","minecraft:dirt"]}
give @s netherite_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:pumpkin"]}
```

How can I do this in Bedrock Edition?

---

[Browse more workarounds for getting/setting NBT in Bedrock Edition](/q/334102/250180)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BE equivalents of these tags are `minecraft:can_place_on` and `minecraft:can_destroy` respectively. You can use these in the [`/give`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give) and [`/replaceitem`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/replaceitem) commands using the final `[components: json]` argument. For example, the syntax of `/give` is:

```
give <player: target> <itemName: Item> [amount: int] [data: int] [components: json]
```

Note that unlike Java Edition, block names go inside an array named `blocks` that goes inside `minecraft:can_place_on` and `minecraft:can_destroy`. Like so:

```
give @s stone 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["grass","dirt"]}}
give @s netherite_axe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["pumpkin"]}}
```

You can also combine both `minecraft:can_place_on` and `minecraft:can_destroy`:

```
give @s iron_block 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["iron_block"]},"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass","dirt"]}}
```

**N.B.** The namespace ID (`minecraft:`) is optional before the words `can_place_on` or `can_destroy`, and can be omitted. However, concerning block IDs, the namespace ID is *forbidden* and must not be present.

Unfortunately, these components only go as specfic as the block IDs, which can be limiting as some blocks rely on data values for variants or positioning. For example, it is impossible to specify a specific color of concrete, as the block ID `concrete` is used by all concrete colors. This is unlike Java Edition, where data values have been abolished in favour of separate block IDs for each variant.

---

This syntax is called [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which is a format similar to the NBT used in JE commands (technically SNBT). Objects are surrounded by braces (`{` and `}`), have keys and values separated by colons (`:`), and have key-value pairs separated by commas (`,`). Keys and strings are surrounded by double quotes (`"`); arrays are surrounded by brackets (`[` and `]`) and contain items delimited by commas (`,`).

Comment: While this answer is correct, note that `can_place_on` is *far* less flexible in Bedrock than in Java because of the way blocks are described. All the concrete colors have a block type of `concrete`, with different `data` values. So while in Java you can give a player a candle than can only be placed on a certain color of concrete, in Bedrock this is not possible. There is a [Mojang bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-97021) on this.

Comment: @NickK9 Now that you mention it, I'm surprised that the note on data values wasn't mentioned in the answer. I was in part responsible for organizing the information on this regard along with several others, and that must have slipped my mind. I've edited the answer accordingly to include that as I think it is important to note.