# Can place on /give is not working

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Minecraft in Windows 10 edition and I type

```
/give @s gold_block 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:planks"]}
```

in-game chat but I keep getting the response,

```
Line 1, Column 2 missing '}' or object member name
```

I've tried looking up people answering this question but nothing is helping me solve this problem. What can I do to get this command to work or at least get this block with those features.

FYI, I'm pretty sure this command works in my version because the can_destory command does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374598/how-can-i-use-canplaceon-and-candestroy-in-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

```
/give @s gold_block 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["minecraft:planks"]}}
```

It needs to be in quotes, underscore-separated words instead of camel cased, and in an array called `blocks`.

Answer (score 0):

Item properties are formatted as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). Therefore, make an object called "can_place_on" with an array "blocks" with all the blocks you want to place it on.

The command would look like this:

```
/give @a <block> 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["<block1>","<block2>"]}}
```

#### Example

Here’s an example. You will receive one redstone torch that can be placed on a stone block:

```
/give @a redstone_torch 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["minecraft:stone"]}}
```

Hope that helped!